# How to fully utilize my Fidelity IRA account?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, fidelity, target-date-fund

Both my wife and I have Fidelity IRA accounts, but I've never fully utilized it.  I'd like to seed this account throughout the year, but I have questions:

- How much money can I put in per year?  What if I exceed it?
- With the Roth IRA, is there an income threshold?  We file jointly, and average around $180k per year.
- Does Fidelity provide any kind of metering or reporting to make sure I do this correctly?
- Also, I'd like to use a targeted retirement fund (like Fidelity Freedom 2035 Fund FFTHX) - can I use this in my Roth IRA account?

Comment: Fidelity? Aren't they a little expensive? (I mean in terms of fund fees, not account fees.)

Comment: @fennec - based on my most recent research, fund fees run around an average of 0.7%.  It's worse than Vanguard.  They do, as everyone says, have wonderful customer service if that matters to you.

Answer (score 3):

- Here's information about [contribution limits](http://www.irs.gov/retirement/participant/article/0,,id=188232,00.html).
- You fall [above the threshold a bit](http://www.brighthub.com/money/investing/articles/47724.aspx).
- I don't know.  I've never overcontributed, so can't say.  You can contribute well into 2011 for 2010 tax year, so if you undershoot just make up the difference.
- I don't see why not!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Some questions wheren't answered, though:

- Will Fidelity alert me if I exceed the limit per year?
- What happens if I do?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that one.  I'm sure they'll tell you if you give them a call!

Answer (score 0):

The limits for 2011 and 2012 are $5000 or $6000 if you are 50 or older. The 2011 income limit is $169K, but that's MAGI, not gross. With a $180K income, your MAGI is likely below $169, but you can only tell by looking at your return. If you are this close, you might have to convert to a non-deducted IRA, or withdraw the money. Else, you can fund the 2011 IRA when you file the return in 2012 to be sure.